alternative for npx react-native link command
this command isnt working to link assets to the project.
npx react-native link

the error says:

unknown command 'link'

to link the assets with project app in react native
even if i use npx react-native-asset command., i still face errors:
$ npx react-native-asset
node:fs:1643
  const stats = binding.lstat(
                        ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\dbzna\Desktop\mern stack\blooddonation1\client\assets\fonts'
    at Object.lstatSync (node:fs:1643:25)
    at loadAsset (C:\Users\dbzna\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\545c366a5ae830a2\node_modules\react-native-asset\lib\index.js:80:22)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\dbzna\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\545c366a5ae830a2\node_modules\react-native-asset\lib\index.js:94:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\dbzna\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\545c366a5ae830a2\node_modules\react-native-asset\lib\index.js:288:6)     
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dbzna\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\545c366a5ae830a2\node_modules\react-native-asset\lib\cli.js:56:1)    
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)     
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32) {       
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\dbzna\\Desktop\\mern stack\\blooddonation1\\client\\assets\\fonts'
}

Node.js v20.11.1

I had the same problem, the solution was to check the file
react-native.config.js
checking the route that was in 'assets' I had it wrong.
